# How to implement a validation code component

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I have to implement a validation code component where the user has to introduce a 4 digit code in 4 diferent edit text but I don't know how to start. Never have I seen an example of this and on the internet I can't find any example.

This is what i want to implmenent:

[image]

Any help would be a appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if there's a made component but what I would do is use a LinearLayout to place the EditText inside it and change the view focus once text was inputted in the previous editText

Answer (score -1):

You can quickly implement this by using a 3rd party library.
I attached a [link](https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/android-otpview-pinview) which I have used in my own projects. it is
simple to set up. maybe it helps you!